# whats the meaning of this line of code in python

Tags: python

i know what is this :

```
self.test2 = struct.unpack('I', header.read(4))[0]
```

but
i can not understand what is this :

```
self.lastFileCreated = "f_%06x" % \
                                       self.test2

just : "f_%06x" % \
```

Comment: It's okay, brother.
I just wanted to remind you about code formatting.
Use: `code`

Comment: It is related to [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: thanks.im not python programmer. and dont know about python. i want just to revers this source code

Comment: MetallimaX , can you please tell me more about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just storing the last file name in string format with `hexa value` of `self.test2` value,

`self.test2 = struct.unpack('I', header.read(4))[0]`  this seem to be number.

more info [string format](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

example

```
>> "f_%06x"%1
'f_000001'
>>> "f_%06x"%23454323432342
'f_1554e29ddb96'
>>> "f_%06x"%234543
'f_03942f'
>>> "f_%06x"%2345
'f_000929'
>>> "f_%06x"%23
'f_000017'
>>> "f_%06x"%1
'f_000001'
>>> "f_%06x"%2
'f_000002'
>>> "f_%06x"%9
'f_000009'
>>> "f_%06x"%10
'f_00000a'
>>> "f_%06x"%11
'f_00000b'
>>> "f_%06x"%16
'f_000010'
>>> "f_%06x"%15
'f_00000f'
```

Comment: yes. the result of test2 is number . for example 15 .
but after < "f_%06x" % \ test2 > , that number change .
and the result of self.lastFileCreated will be < f_00000f >

Comment: you need to see how `repr` method is writte in your class

Comment: how %2345 convert to 'f_000929' in your example ?

Comment: don''t know about c# , but how the value convert go through [convert decimal to hexadecimal](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html)

Comment: i am sorry. hust tell me witout code, how the result of "f_%06x"%2345 is 'f_000929' ?

Comment: [convert decimal to hexadecimal](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter) step by step

Comment: i know and now i convert that code to c# ... :)